# flex 4 DropDownListSkin binding itemDestructionPolicy to variable value

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

`itemDestructionPolicy` has two possible values: `never` and `auto`

I tried to bind the value to a parameter instead of writing the value, I got this error:

> Invalid value for `itemDestructionPolicy` attribute.

Code example:

```js
package com.hp.esb.skin.light.dropdownlist 
{
    public class ItemDestructionPolicy 
    {
        public static const NEVER:String = "never";
        public static const AUTO:String = "auto";
    }
}
```

DropDownListSkin:

```xml
<s:PopUpAnchor id="popUp" displayPopUp.normal="false" displayPopUp.open="true" includeIn="open"
               itemDestructionPolicy="{hostComponent.destructionPolicy}"
               popUpPosition="below" popUpWidthMatchesAnchorWidth="true">
```

DropDownList:

```js
[Bindable]
public var destructionPolicy:String = ItemDestructionPolicy.NEVER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itemDestructionPolicy it is compile time attribute so you can't bind it.